# Where do I begin with photography?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, photography-basics, learning, tips

Starting photography was in the back of my head for the last couple of years. Now that a new year is approaching I want to make this happen. I just want to say that I have no idea where do I begin. The only camera that I own at the moment is that of my cell phone.

I am really interested in black/white photography and people seem to think that's a good place to start. I managed to save around 450 euros so that's my budget. Any input you have for me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @dpollitt although the questions are similar I think the specified black and white differ it enough. However it is rather broad.

Comment: Are you talking about analog photography or digital photography?

Comment: @CrazyDino Disagreed. Black and white is an artistic choice (usually made in post). It doesn't change any of the answers in the linked dupe IMO.

Comment: @scottbb depends. If someone explicitly wants to do black and white photography I would point them in the direction of black and white film. Learn to shoot and think about composition rather than a spray and pray and then convert to black and white. You then have the method of conversion, on cam 'picture-styles', proper post processing (desaturation+curves etc) or just simple conversion in say Windows picture viewer.

Comment: Although you are 100% right that the answers are valid in the other one.

Comment: @JeffreyMichael Please place answers as answers, not as comments. For why, please see: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a camera that allows you to manually set shutter speed and aperture. Learn about these concepts and start shooting.

Additionally it may be useful to follow a photography class. Weekly assignments will get you out there taking pictures and start you to think before you shoot.
Plus the added fun of seeing other peoples work and discussing it.